# Recommended size for site logo in SharePoint(Office 365)

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, site-logo, size

**What I have**:

I am using SharePoint online which is part of Office 365.

**Question**:

What is the best size/ratio of a logo in this case?

(Rectangular one, in type of the old version of SharePoint looks bad and is too small).

Is square the solution? or something like 168 x 80 pixels?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

64x64 .png file is recommended. SharePoint will downsize, but you want to avoid any extra scaling
[image]

Comment: Just as an addition: SharePoint fits the logo into max-height: 64px and max-width: 192px. So, if for some reason the logo doesn't work with a square image, the size/ratio should be within these bounds.

Answer (score 1):

I've used square, and if it's too big SPO will automatically downsize to fit.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to change the logo size, you can refer to this article:

http://webbrewers.com/change-logo-size-office-365-sharepoint-2013-public-site/?i=1