# SharePoint Online Modern Experience Logo and Favicon

Tags: branding, modern-experience, site-logo

What is the recommended size/resolution for Logo and Favicon for SharePoint Online Modern Experience?

Answer (score 0):

[For Site logo](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/265979/recommended-size-for-site-logo-in-sharepointoffice-365) size is 64x64 pixels .png

---

[For Favicon](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2014/05/how-to-change-favicon-in-sharepoint-2013.html) size is 16x16 pixels .ico

Place the custom favicon in "Site Assets" and update master page as:

```
<!--SPM:<SharePoint:SPShortcutIcon runat="server" IconUrl="http://sharepoint.YOURSITE.com/PATH/fav.ico"/>-->
```

[Steps](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/how-to-change-the-favicon-in-the-sharepoint-online)